# Checkbox Group Array to String Conversion Error

Tags: php

I have a checkbox group array that is posting arrays, but not in my email. I'm using this code to 'implode' the arrays:

```
<?php
    if ( !empty($form->data['student']) && is_array($form->data['student'] ) ) {
      $session = array();
      foreach ( $form->data['student'] as $s ) {
      $session[] = "<tr><td>{$s['schoosedayM']}</td></tr><tr><td>{$s['sxcareM']}</td></tr>";
      }
    }
    $form->data['session_data'] = implode("\n", $session);
    ?>
```

Does anyone know how I can get the checkbox group arrays to post in my email?

Comment: What's happening?  What output do you see?  Which line is giving this error?  Have you tried to `var_dump($s)` in the loop?

Comment: I see the data array, which is fine. But I get an error message saying 'Array to string conversion' with this message when using var_dump:

array(2) { ["schoosedayM"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "Half Day (AM)" [1]=> string(13) "Half Day (PM)" [2]=> string(4) "None" } ["sxcareM"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "8 to 9 AM" [1]=> string(10) "12 to 1 PM" [2]=> string(12) "4 to 5:30 PM" [3]=> string(4) "None" } }

Comment: Looks like `$s['schoosedayM']` and `$s['sxcareM']` are arrays.  You probably want to [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) them.